# Shortcut or widget for contact on iphone home screen? Iphone 13, ios 16.2

Tags: iphone, contacts

Shortcut or widget for contact on iphone home screen?

Iphone 13, ios 16.2

Appreciate someone perhaps walking through these steps with their iphone, trying them and correcting them and verbiage, if you would be so very kind.

​
SHORTCUT Direction  FOR CONTACTS ON HOME SCREEN. But tricky to get working for me. I want to add 4 contacts. No pics but different icons and names of course.
Install and open the Shortcuts app on your iPhone. If not already on iPhone.
Tap the Gallery action if you want in lower corner
In search panel enter "Contact" and tap on "Contact on Home Screen Option" (tap 3 dots, might need to click on hamburger icons)
Tap the set up shortcut option
From my Shortcuts Tap on the “+” icon at the top. Give shortcut a name
Tap a suggested contact. To call someone else type the tiny plus icon.
Might need to select "Call" to call a contact. ?????
If you clicked tiny plus icon, tap the faint blue "Contact" word and select a person from your address book. ?????????
Give a name to your shortcut in the “Shortcut Name” field like "Ros".
Tap Setting icon on top right OR is it the Share with arrow at bottom?
Tap Add to Home screen
Tap the tiny shortcut icon and pick a photo or something else, diffenet icon ???????
Tap Add again--it should be on the home screen
Repeat to add another contact

​ appreciate someone walking through and see if it works correctly and correcting what I wrote or gathered.

Secondly
My second question is is there a way to have the shortcut not dial the person immediately or should I just use a widget instead? I want to avoid erroneous dialing by touching the screen contact by accident

Thank you very much and have a good New Year and I appreciate your time

Peter